# Change argument in jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

How can I pass an argument to a jQuery function, change it and then keep the change after function is executed? In the below example the argument is changed in the function but does not keep its value after function terminated. Do I need to add a keyword like `$.fn.myfunction = function(ref a)`?

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.myfunct = function(a)
    {
        arguments[0]='test';                
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var a='1';
    $().myfunct(a);
    alert(a);
});
```

Comment: You could only simulate this by passing an object to the function and modify one of its properties.

Comment: JavaScript does not support pointers. The closest thing to what you're trying to do is references, but they don't work on primitive types. You'll have to use an object.

Comment: Why do you want this as a jQuery function?

Comment: Many thanks Felix King